# get all rows from orignal Dataframe which is having number or alpha number in particular column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe Like this in df_init

```
          column1
       0  hi all, i am fine
       1  How are you ? 123 a45
       2  123444234324!!!  (This is also string)
       3  sdsfds sdfsdf 233423
       5  adsfd xcvbb cbcvbcvcbc
```

I want to get all those values from this dataframe which is having a number or alpha number
I am expecting like this in df_final

```
          column1
       0  How are you ? 123 a45
       1  123444234324!!!  (This is also string)
       2  sdsfds sdfsdf 233423
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `\d` for match number and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.column1.str.contains('\d')]
print (df)
                                  column1
1                   How are you ? 123 a45
2  123444234324!!!  (This is also string)
3                    sdsfds sdfsdf 233423
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
                  column1
0   hi all, i am fine d78
1   How are you ? 123 a45
2         123444234324!!!
3    sdsfds sdfsdf 233423
4  adsfd xcvbb cbcvbcvcbc
5                 234324@
6                 123! vc

df = df[df.column1.str.contains(r'^\d+[<!\-[.*?\]>@]+$')]
print (df)
           column1
2  123444234324!!!
5          234324@
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, what if i want row which has only number, in above case only row 2 (eg: 123444234324!!!)

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali -hmm, do you think only number with some string after like `123444234324!!!` or `123444234324aaa` ?

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali - or only number like `123444234324` or `456` in one row?

Comment: I want all value with number and special character only eg(123444234324!!, 2342524@, 346547568324-2324). In 123444234324aaa e have an alphabet.

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali - Can you check `df = df[df.column1.str.contains(r'\d+[<!\-[.*?\]>@]+')]` ?

Comment: No, it is not working, it is returning me those record also which has alphabet, the number with special character. i want those record only which has number and alphabet.

Comment: Edited one is working partially, it is not working for the casses if we have special character at the start of the string (eg: !!2455436)

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali - What about `df = df[df.column1.str.contains(r'^[<!\-[.*?\]>@]*\d+[<!\-[.*?\]>@]*$')]` ?